# Need good instructions on how to set up Office365 API in order to access logs (so we can save/export beyond 90day)

Tags: logging, office365, office365api, elk

Microsoft has a 90 window of saving office 365 / Azure logs.  We thought we could get away with exporting from the Security/Compliance center every 90 days, I recently discovered there is a 50k line limit in the exported excel csv.  After some testing it seems we generate more than 50k lines of data per 3 days.

So I need a way of being able to stream out these logs to storage at least, without intervention.  I discovered the ELK stack as a good resource, but- it requires configuration of the office365 api for which I just can't get through the instructions properly.  Can someone break it down for me?

Else - if someone could tell me a better solution, I just need to get these logs safely saved somewhere everyday.. . .

thanks
JoeJoe

Answer (score 0):

Call the API to grab all events daily, hourly, or whichever interval gives you under 50k results.  Feed this events to your service however you wish.  Store the most recent timestamp in a flat file and any consecutive calls to the API will filter using this timestamp.